# Identify what replacement DVD module to purchase

Tags: nintendo-wii

Our Wii Family Edition (RVL-101 USA) has stopped reading the game disks we put in. All other functions work well. Following some manuals I found online, I opened and cleaned up the internals (down to the laser lens), but it did not help. A few replacement drives are available for purchase online, but it seems like there are multiple variants of the part (and title usually say D2A D2B D2C etc., which I understand is the code of the decoder chip).

[One page lists many of the known drive and controller board versions](https://www.wiidrives.com/howto). The most similar is the very last one, on the right side (which they name as D3-2/D3S/D4). The PCB is same shape, but our console has just the two larger chips instead of all three:

[image]

Of all the replacement drives I could find, the best match (visually) are similar to the one in the page I linked to above.

**Can anyone identify this board revision?**

**Are the various DVD replacement drives that are in the market compatible?**

Note: If you think there is a better forum for this question, please let me know.

Comment: id suggest the letterbomb exploit and other homebrew apps to install your disks to a thumbdrive....this is much easier to setup than the trouble you have already taken and cheaper than buying new parts that are due to fail not to mention risking damage to your disks every time you use them....by now im sure you have no warranty and wii live functions are already disabled so theres no reason to not put the homebrew fixes to use....

Comment: @Firobug - Thanks! This is certainly one of the options I considered. However, to the best of my understanding, you'd need a working drive to make the image, won't you? Given the cost of the replacement (~$20), I would like to try that path first and get to the soft-solution as a last resort. I also found used consoles in my area sold for some $50 on Craigslist. But, I don't want all the crap that comes with the CL ones.

Comment: no all you need is a sd card and the letterbomb from please.hack.me then from your pc you can install the files with wii backup manager to a usb...there are some complicated steps if you want extra features and note if you come across a step that prompts you for a special cios install never agree to an option for piracy sake as it will often corrupt things on you....I had this when trying to get a gamecube emulator working...I think it was cios 136 or something...

Comment: remember please.hack.me ; homebrew channel; priiloader; configurable usb loader; wiiflow;  and wii backup manager are most important...with some games like monster hunter 3 you will need the special installers to make custom merged cios files and assign the game to that cios

Comment: best to follow complete guides I recomend the one from youtube which links you to the packages with all the wad files and everything I think it was 3/4 parts....

Comment: @Firobug - what a waste of precious time.... After spending hours reading through guides, installing step-by-step (worrying not to brick the box), getting HBC, BootMii, the IOS to enable backup image loading from USB, I finally got to try and create an ISO - - just to find out that there's really a minimal list of PC DVD drives that are compatible w/ Wii discs.... As I mentioned above, unless you have a compatible DVD drive, you most probably need a working Wii in order to create these backups. What a bummer!

Comment: wiiflow along with many other discoverable loaders will allow you to load from the usb drive instead...no disks needed....that is why you format a card with wii backup management software iso images can reasonably be recovered.....only a handfull of games may not work right...some require special cios installs generally 222 as a combined form of two other cios files....though I also hear wiiflow works nice fat32....

Comment: @Firobug - how do you extract the DVD to an image (ISO or whatever) to begin with? If your Wii's DVD drive is faulty, your alternative is to use your friend's soft-modded Wii (I don't have one) or use you PC. But, only a handful of PC DVD drives are known to read Wii discs. 4 of my computers (including a decade old Dell D800) can't.

Comment: I would think it would be an oppurtune time then to start the thing at backing up your disks to at least 1tb as sizes range at 2-12gb maybe but if you have a substantial library still a softmodded backup would be fully advisible..I think wiiflow allowed backup or maybe it was cfg...sry I didnt respond sooner to you but I would have suggested rom sites would help give you the right direction for recovering your files...

Comment: @Firobug - thanks. Yes, this definitely crossed my mind, if I just find some time to breathe... BTW, found this pretty comprehensive site: https://sites.google.com/site/completesg/home and followed their modding instructions up to the point of needing a compatible drive.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp2shEl5n8Y think thats the site instructions I followed being sure to follow links on description....but several work fine especially as you get expetienced at it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying my luck in soft-modding the unit, attempt ended up unsuccessful due to the incompatibility of PC DVD drives with the Wii game DVDs. [used [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/completesg/home) as a guide]

So I ended up purchasing a replacement DVD unit. It was not identical to my original one, but the board was of the same form-factor. The units are claimed by the seller to be cross-compatible.

After installing the replacement, my Wii now works as before, reading the various discs I tried throwing in.

For reference, [here's the iFixit tutorial used to take the console apart for replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Wii+DVD+Drive+Lens+Replacement/4491#s16511).

[image]